# Use a route with an id to mimic a node type but pull from a third party source?

Tags: 8, routes

Is it possible in Drupal 8 to create a route like `/events/{id}` with a controller, and in that controller make a call to a third party API to fetch data and then send that data to a template? It basically would not exist in Drupal as an entity.

Comment: Sure, that would be a single route and a few lines of code only. What’s the connection to node types?

Comment: Not much. Was just using that as an example.

Comment: Then it's straight up yes, just write the code to do exactly what you've described and it'll work (declare a route with a parameter, in the controller method for that route make an API call, or better yet inject a custom service that contains that functionality, then return a render array referencing a theme item that does what you want)

Comment: To answer even more generically. A route can be anything that you can do in PHP and return as a response (render array or response object).

Comment: yes, that's all you need, though caching can be a bit tricky, because for non-database content no tags are invalidated when the data is modified, so you might need to add a custom cache tag and a cron job to invalidate (cache-max age doesn't help if it is cached in the internal page cache).

Comment: Is it possible to generate a human friendly path for it?

Comment: Yes, you can use aliases. If you mean automatically generate aliases, then you need custom code, because Pathauto only works for entities. You probably need to fetch the third party API data first to determine for example which title to use for the path.

Comment: Yeah. Probably not going to store any of it locally in Drupal. I am fine with it not being aliased, just asking.